# "Open in Word" randomly is missing when Office Web Apps views word docs

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-addin, office-web-apps

I have the following random issue. We are using SharePoint 2013 with Office Web Apps for view office docs. The editing in browser for OWA is turned off. Editors get an "Open in Word/Excel" option

This option randomly is missing off. There doesnt seem to be any pattern to it.

We do have Anonymous access enabled on this Web Application.

What we should get:[image]

What we do get: [image]

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Cheers

Ed Dempsey